# Node/Express: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the below code where I am trying to validate a user with its credentials from Mongo DB :

```
{
  validate: async function (email, password, res) {
    console.log('Inside validate method');

    try {
      var dbUserObj = await User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {

        console.log('Inside validate method111111');

        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).send('Error on the server.');
        }

        console.log('Inside validate method 22222');

        if (!user) {
          return res.status(404).send('No user found.');
        }

        console.log('Inside validate method33333');

        var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

        console.log('Is Valid Password :: ' + passwordIsValid);

        if (!passwordIsValid) {
          return res.status(401).send({
            auth: false,
            token: null
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {

    }

    console.log('DDDDBBBB USSSERRRR :::' + dbUserObj);
    return dbUserObj;
  }
}
```

The below code calls the validate method :

```
var auth = {

login: function(req, res,next) {

 console.log('Inside login');
var email = req.body.email || '';
var password=req.body.password || '';
console.log('Before validate user');
// Fire a query to your DB and check if the credentials are valid
var dbUserObj = auth.validate(email,password,res);

if (!dbUserObj) { // If authentication fails, we send a 401 back
  res.status(401);
  res.json({
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Invalid credentials"
  });
  return;
}

if (dbUserObj) {      
  res.send(genToken(dbUserObj));

}
```

}

Whenever there is a condition when the password is incorrect i am getting the error :

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Cannot really figure out the issue.

Comment: How are you *using* this function? It seems like your endpoint handler is returning before this call completes, hence the error.

Comment: Your function has 2 points... One if the password is not valid, and another one... You cannot do this... Even if you code `return res.send`the function goes on....

Comment: What do you do after calling validate()? If you execute `res.send()` at some point after it, that could be the problem because you already do that when returning 401.

Comment: Edited the original post with the calling function

Answer (score 2):

The route that calls your `validate()` needs to accept [the `next` callback parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) from express, otherwise the framework assumes that when the asynchronous function returns (which occurs at the first `await` expression), it has completed all its work and at that point it continues down its routes to the default error handling which sends a 404 before your database query resumes async control flow in `validate`.

When your route handler accepts the `next` parameter, it indicates to express that the route will handle asynchronously, and you can do 1 of 3 things:

1. Don't call `next()` if you already send a response (which you always do in this case).
2. Call `next()` with no arguments if you don't send a response and want to delegate the response handling to the remaining routes.
3. Call `next(error)` if you want to delegate the response handling to remaining middleware which will handle the error reporting and response for you.

Comment: @souvikc `login: async function` and `var dbUserObj = await auth.validate(email,password,res);`

Comment: @ Patrick it worked thanks.Can you please explain me a bit here what was the issue ?

Comment: @souvikc [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).